# Lazy initialization of ArrayList attribute fails (EclipseLink -> Hibernate migration)

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, wildfly

I migrated a **Java EE** war website from GlassFish 4 to **WildFly**.

Glassfish uses EclipseLink, WildFly uses Hibernate. I am using Java Server Faces with CDI Named beans. One of my beans directly calls a dao class method to retrieve Category object. The Category class has some attributes, one of them is List merchandise. This is by default lazily initialized (Merchandise is another table). The Category object is retrieved, but when trying to work with List merchandise, which is lazily initialized, the persistence bag is empty and following error is thrown:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: cz.pscheidl.velkoobchod.domain.Category.merchandise, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I think I know what kind of problem this is. The @Named bean called EshopBean does not provide any transaction when calling this object. This should not work in Glassfish, but somehow it did. After setting EAGER initialization of List merchandise in Category object, everything works. So does JOIN FETCH in related named query.

EshopBean object looks like this:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class EshopBean implements Serializable {


    @Inject private CategoryDao categoryDao;
    @Inject private MerchandiseDao merchandiseDao;
    @Inject private ActiveSession activeSession;
    @Inject private OrderDao orderDao;
    @Inject private Logger logger;


    private List<Category> categoryList;
    private List<OrderItem> offeredMerchandise;


    @PostConstruct
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void updateOfferedMerchandise() {
        List<Category> allCateogries = categoryDao.findByOffered(true);
        offeredMerchandise = new ArrayList<>();
        categoryList = new ArrayList<>();

        allCateogries.parallelStream().filter(e -> {
        return !e.getMerchandise().isEmpty();
        }).forEach(e -> {
        categoryList.add(e);

        e.getMerchandise().parallelStream().filter(m -> {
            return m.isOffered();}).forEach(m -> {
            offeredMerchandise.add(createOrderItem(m));
            });

        });
    }
}
```

Category object looks like this (methods omitted):

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(
        {
            @NamedQuery(name = "findCategoryByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.name = :name"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "findAllCategories", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "categoryHasMerchandise", query = "SELECT COUNT(m) FROM Merchandise m WHERE m.category = :categoryId"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "findCategoryByOffered", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.offered = :offered")
        }
)
public class Category implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean offered;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    public List<Merchandise> merchandise;
}
```

CategoryDaoImpl (some methods omitted):

```
@Stateless
public class CategoryDaoImpl implements CategoryDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public List<Category> findByOffered(boolean activity) {
        Query findByOfferedQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findCategoryByOffered", Category.class);
        findByOfferedQuery.setParameter("offered", true);
        return findByOfferedQuery.getResultList();
    }
}
```

The method calling chain is like this: EshopBean.updateOfferedMerchandise()  - > CategoryDaoImpl.findByOffered() - > return to EshopBean.updateOfferedMerchandise(). I'd guess that both are annotated as transactional, findByOffered method is annotated as Required. Yet Hibernate in WildFly says there is no session (i think it expects the same transactional context).

**Question summary:** I want to keep merchnadise lazily initialized and correct the session issue, so the bag with merchandise is lazily initialized in EshopBean.updateOfferedMerchandise() method. Do I really need to JOIN FETCH or set Lazy initialization to false ? How to set transactions right for this code to start working ?

Comment: JOIN FETCH would be correct process.

Comment: and about your second question I am not getting what you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when applications are migrated off Glassfish onto Wildfly. Unfortunately, Wildfly's default Hibernate JPA implementation does not allow you to fetch a lazy relationship after the context has been closed, unlike EclipseLink.

Many solutions advise refactoring with eager fetches, but this is not a good solution because eager fetches increase responses and you introduce risk into a working application by refactoring the database access.

Rather replace Hibernate with EclipseLink as the JPA Persistence Provider in Wildfly.  [This library](https://github.com/jipijapa/jipijapa/tree/master/eclipselink) of utility classes integrates EclipseLink into Wildfly and [the instructions are here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink).

What you have to do is copy **eclipselink-2.6.0.jar** (or whatever version you are using) into **[WILDFLY_HOME]/modules/system/layers/base/org/eclipse/persistence/main** and then edit **module.xml** in the same folder to include the JAR:

```
<resources>
   <resource-root path="jipijapa-eclipselink-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
   <resource-root path="eclipselink-2.6.0.jar">           
      <filter>
         <exclude path="javax/**" />
      </filter>
   </resource-root>
</resources>
```

Don't forget to reboot the server.